# how LGBM handles the categorical features without specification

Tags: scala, lightgbm

I am playing with LGBM and indexed my categorical features using StingIndexer. but after that I haven't tell my model which features is categorical features. So, I am wondering how it knows which features are categorical features

Here is how I init my LGBM model.

```
val lgbm = new LightGBMClassifier("lgbm").
  setObjective("binary").
  setFeatureFraction(0.85).
  setFeaturesCol("features").
  setLabelCol("is_booker")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `mmlspark` (you  didn't mention how you're using LightGBM in Scala), LightGBM  automatically figures out which columns should be treated as categorical, based on the attributes of the columns.

From [Azure/mmlspark#559](https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/issues/559#issuecomment-488539589):

> ...if you use string indexer or our value indexer, categorical metadata will be automatically added to the dataframe and lightgbm will actually be able to interpret it and treat those columns as categoricals by splitting on the feature values directly (so you won't need to one-hot-encode them)

The method that accomplishes that is called `LightGBMUtils.getCategoricalIndexes()`, and you can find it at https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/95c1f8a782191e3578587a49313e1d57abee5da3/src/main/scala/com/microsoft/ml/spark/lightgbm/LightGBMUtils.scala#L74-L104.

That method is re-used by `LightGBMBase.getCategoricalIndexes()` during training:

- definition: https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/96f0b7775629d6e7b521d1ed8ca0e54655deef00/src/main/scala/com/microsoft/ml/spark/lightgbm/LightGBMBase.scala#L149-L159
- use: https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/96f0b7775629d6e7b521d1ed8ca0e54655deef00/src/main/scala/com/microsoft/ml/spark/lightgbm/LightGBMBase.scala#L211.

If I'm right that you're using `mmlspark` and you have further questions about how this works, I recommend opening issues in [Azure/mmlspark](https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/issues).